# Number of elements of the largest set family satisfying the condition

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let the set $S = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Let T be a family of sets of S. Every element of T has 5 elements.

If two distinct elements A and B of T always satisfy
$|A \cap B| \leq 3 $

what is the maximum number of elements in T?

**Additional context**

The program has shown that the number of elements of $T$ can exist up to $36$.
Can you prove that there is no $T$ with more than 37 elements?

We want to find the maximum number of elements of T that satisfy the condition.
I would like a mathematical proof.

I have seen similar problems on Web sites before.
That web site is no longer there and I can no longer check the problem.
I remember that in the original problem, the set S had about 120 elements, not 10.

---

The following is an example of a set family T.
T has 36 elements.

\begin{eqnarray}
\{\{2,3,4,5,6\},\{0,4,6,8,9\},\{1,2,3,6,7\},\{0,1,6,7,9\}, \\
\{1,2,4,5,8\},\{0,2,4,5,9\},\{0,2,5,6,7\},\{0,1,2,6,8\}, \\
\{2,3,4,7,9\},\{1,5,6,7,8\},\{3,4,5,8,9\},\{0,1,2,3,5\}, \\
\{0,1,3,7,8\},\{2,5,6,8,9\},\{1,2,4,6,9\},\{0,4,5,7,8\}, \\
\{4,5,6,7,9\},\{1,2,3,8,9\},\{1,4,7,8,9\},\{0,2,3,6,9\}, \\
\{3,6,7,8,9\},\{1,3,4,6,8\},\{2,4,6,7,8\},\{0,1,5,8,9\}, \\
\{1,3,5,6,9\},\{0,1,2,4,7\},\{0,2,3,4,8\},\{0,2,7,8,9\}, \\
\{1,3,4,5,7\},\{0,3,5,7,9\},\{0,1,4,5,6\},\{2,3,5,7,8\}, \\
\{0,3,5,6,8\},\{0,1,3,4,9\},\{0,3,4,6,7\},\{1,2,5,7,9\}\}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. What did you try ?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "Every element of T has element number 5": do you mean it has five elements? + [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I have created a program to count the number of subsets and have succeeded in creating up to 36 subsets.
The following subset families.
0,2,3,6,8 / 3,5,6,7,9 / 1,4,7,8,9 / 3,4,6,7,8 / 0,1,2,7,8 / 1,2,4,6,9 / 2,4,5,7,8 / 1,2,5,7,9 / 0,1,3,5,6 / 0,1,4,6,8 / 0,5,6,7,8 / 0,2,3,5,7 / 0,1,2,4,5 / 0,3,7,8,9 / 0,1,5,8,9 / 1,4,5,6,7 / 1,3,6,8,9 / 2,3,4,7,9 / 0,2,5,6,9 / 0,2,4,8,9 / 0,3,4,5,8 / 4,5,6,8,9 / 0,1,3,4,7 / 0,3,4,6,9 / 0,4,5,7,9 / 2,3,4,5,6 / 2,6,7,8,9 / 1,2,3,6,7 / 0,1,6,7,9 / 1,2,5,6,8 / 0,1,2,3,9 / 2,3,5,8,9 / 1,3,5,7,8 / 0,2,4,6,7 / 1,3,4,5,9 / 1,2,3,4,8

Comment: "Every element of T has element number 5": do you mean it has five elements? 
Yes.

Comment: @Tofu This has to be included in the main post. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Aig, Thanks for the advice.
I have rewritten the question using MathJax.

Comment: You should ask this question in a more general form at mathoverflow.

Comment: This is an instance of the much investigated *set packing problem*. I don't know the answer, but a trivial upper bound is $|T|\le\binom{10}4/5=42$.

Comment: @bof How do you argue for that bound?

Comment: @mbsq For distinct $X,Y\in T$ we have $\binom X4\cap\binom Y4=\varnothing$ where $\binom X4$ denotes the set of all $4$-element subsets of $X$. Therefore $$5|T|=\left|\bigcup_{X\in T}\binom X4\right|\le\binom{10}4.$$